# Passing gesture events from pivot to child element

Tags: windows-phone-8.1

I understand this is almost always a no go, however I have an item on a pivot control that that I'd like to pass gestures to in Windows Phone 8.1.

I have a color-picker residing on one of the pivots and I'd like the user to still be able to touch, and slide the color picker item around to select their color.

I don't want to abandon this just yet, but I've tried disabling the IsHitTestVisible to false, but this obviously does not help as all child items are not reachable.

I've not found much else on this subject, specifically to disable the pivot's own gesture or pass it on to the color picker. I would change pages by the pivot headers.

Any suggestions on this? Is it any at all possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you have two options to achieve this

1. Lock the pivot when user interacting with the color picker. You can set `PivotControl.IsLocked=true;` property for this.
2. Show the color picker to a popup like screen on the top of the pivot control.  You can change the visibility of the color picker grid based on some triggers

Comment: Those aren't bad options, but I was hoping to keep the control in the menu, no additional popups and, what I call for this app, clutter. Also, the PivotItems do not have an IsLocked method from what I can tell.

Comment: This has solved my manipulation problems. Hadn't wholly known the Pivot had this attribute.